# Which SQL function can I use to add two numbers together?”

Tags: sql

Which SQL function can I use to add two numbers together?”

Comment: select a + b as c from table_name

Comment: This question is not unclear.  It might be a duplicate, but it's perfectly _clear_.

Answer (score 1):

With the `+` operator:

```
SELECT field1 + field2 FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `SELECT 10 + 9;`
If you need to add column values in a table, then you can go with SUM().
`SELECT SUM(columnName) FROM tableName;`